# Add progressbar to webbrowser on winphone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mpns

My application is a web browser. I added a progressbar to the XAML but the progressbar won't run, or even show up on the GUI, when the browser runs,

My code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(Browser_Navigated);
    webBrowser1.Navigating += new EventHandler<NavigatingEventArgs>(Browser_Navigating);
    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://nhomxe.vn", UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

Progressbar:

```
void Browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    ProgBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

void Browser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ProgBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Xaml:

```
<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ProgressBar Foreground="Green" x:Name="ProgBar" Visibility="Collapsed" IsIndeterminate="True" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" />
        <phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,-12,-13,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsScriptEnabled="True"/>
        <phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser2" Width="1" Height="1" IsScriptEnabled="True"></phone:WebBrowser>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you post your xaml code, your c# code looks correct.

Comment: Can mark the answer as correct if it was satisfactory? If not please tell so i can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use the `ProgressIndicator` in the SystemTry

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator(); // << NEW

    webBrowser1.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(Browser_Navigated);
    webBrowser1.Navigating += new EventHandler<NavigatingEventArgs>(Browser_Navigating);
    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://nhomxe.vn", UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

Create the following method to display the `ProgressIndicator`

```
private void DisplayProgressIndicator(bool isvisible, string message = "")
{
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = message;
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = isvisible;
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = isvisible;
}
```

The modify your event handlers like this.

```
private void Browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayProgressIndicator(true, "Loading...");
}

private void Browser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayProgressIndicator(false);
}
```

That should show the progress of the page loading in the `SystemTry`

Answer (score 0):

Use this Xaml code instead of your Xaml code.

```
        <phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,-12,-13,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsScriptEnabled="True"/>
        <phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser2" Width="1" Height="1" IsScriptEnabled="True"></phone:WebBrowser>
  <ProgressBar Foreground="Green" x:Name="ProgBar" Visibility="Collapsed" IsIndeterminate="True" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" />
    </Grid>
```